# SQL Filter past dates

Tags: php, mysql

I asked a similar question earlier but didn't have all the facts. How would I modify this query to filter out all dates prior to the current date?

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_location_date WHERE location=$id ORDER BY location_date");
```

Complete(ish) code in the function.php file from WordPress.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_fetch_dates', 'get_location_date');
add_action('wp_ajax_fetch_dates', 'get_location_date');
function get_location_date() {
global  $wpdb;
ob_clean();
$id = $_POST['id']; // Get the Request Id;

$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_location_date WHERE location=$id ORDER BY location_date");
foreach ( $result as $value ) {
     $option .= '<option value="'.$value->id.'">';
     $option .= $value->date_coment;
     $option .= '</option>';
    }
 echo '<option value="0" selected="selected">Select Date</option>'.$option;
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I *think* their question was how to adjust the query to filter out records dated earlier than today. (Post modified post to make it more clear)

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_location_date WHERE location=$id and location_date >= curdate() ORDER BY location_date");
```

On a side note, never use raw user input in your SQL queries! Use mysql_real_escape_string on strings and intval on integers, such as

```
$id = intval($_POST['id']);
```

or

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_location_date WHERE location="'.mysql_real_escape_string($id).'" and location_date >= curdate() ORDER BY location_date');
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the data type of location_date?
You could try this:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_location_date WHERE location=$id AND location_date > current_date - 1 ORDER BY location_date");
```

More info on the [MySQL Reference Guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).